# minidump stackwalk vs gdb backtrace

Tags: c++, firefox, gdb, minidump, google-breakpad

I have a vulnerability trigger (CVE-2018-18492) in Firefox, which crashes and gives SIGSEGV. I used breakpad `minidump_stackwalk` to get its stack trace from the minidump file produced with the crash. I got something like below:

```
Thread 0 (crashed)
 0  0xd000b1000d
    rax = 0x00005576254ffac0   rdx = 0x0000000000000000
    rcx = 0x0000000000000001   rbx = 0x0000000000000000
    rsi = 0x0000557623c5e040   rdi = 0x00005576239d7c60
    rbp = 0x00007fffd0546890   rsp = 0x00007fffd0546568
     r8 = 0x0000000044815f7a    r9 = 0x00000000aa7e5e96
    r10 = 0x0000000000000001   r11 = 0x0000000000000001
    r12 = 0x0000557623c5e040   r13 = 0x00007fffd0546910
    r14 = 0x00005576239d7c60   r15 = 0x0000557623c5e040
    rip = 0x000000d000b1000d
    Found by: given as instruction pointer in context
 1  libxul.so!mozilla::dom::HTMLOptionsCollection_Binding::add [HTMLOptionsCollectionBinding.cpp : 165 + 0x1d]
    rbp = 0x00007fffd0546a70   rsp = 0x00007fffd05468a0
    rip = 0x00007f099629754c
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 2  libxul.so!bool mozilla::dom::binding_detail::GenericMethod<mozilla::dom::binding_detail::NormalThisPolicy, mozilla::dom::binding_detail::ThrowExceptions>(JSContext*, unsigned int, JS::Value*) [BindingUtils.cpp : 3296 + 0x9]
    rbx = 0x00007f099c307d10   rbp = 0x00007fffd0546b40
    rsp = 0x00007fffd0546a80   r12 = 0x00000000000000fb
    r13 = 0x00007fffd0546af0   r14 = 0x00007fffd0546ab0
    r15 = 0x00007fffd0546ad0   rip = 0x00007f099638680d
    Found by: call frame info
...
```

Then I ran with the same thing again with gdb (`gdb /path/to/firefox/binary`), it crashes again as expected, and I use `bt` to get the backtrace at the point of crash. However I got something slightly different:

```
#0  0x000055a17135b810 in  ()
#1  0x00007f23dd134dea in nsINode::ReplaceOrInsertBefore(bool, nsINode*, nsINode*, mozilla::ErrorResult&) (this=0x55a1712a3550, aReplace=<optimized out>, aNewChild=<optimized out>, aRefChild=<optimized out>, aError=...) at /home/ug16zy2/firefox-63.0.3/dom/base/nsINode.cpp:2631
#2  0x00007f23dd8b0e7f in mozilla::dom::HTMLOptionsCollection_Binding::add(JSContext*, JS::Handle<JSObject*>, mozilla::dom::HTMLOptionsCollection*, JSJitMethodCallArgs const&) (cx=0x55a16e7867e0, obj=Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> No type "Class" within class or namespace "js".:
0x7f23820aaf40, self=0x55a1701b1600, args=...) at /home/ug16zy2/firefox-63.0.3/objdir-ff-dbg/dom/bindings/HTMLOptionsCollectionBinding.cpp:165
#3  0x00007f23dd953158 in mozilla::dom::binding_detail::GenericMethod<mozilla::dom::binding_detail::NormalThisPolicy, mozilla::dom::binding_detail::ThrowExceptions>(JSContext*, unsigned int, JS::Value*) (cx=0x55a16e7867e0, argc=1, vp=0x55a16f509ed0) at /home/ug16zy2/firefox-63.0.3/dom/bindings/BindingUtils.cpp:3296
...
```

Note the call stack of two outputs. It seems that gdb gives one more function call `ReplaceOrInsertBefore` on top of `add`, whereas minidump did not.

Do you know what causes the difference between them and why?

Comment: If there's memory (including stack) corruption involved you cannot necessarily trust any generated stack trace. Also; for optimized binaries, the debug information may not be 100% reliable. In extreme cases you may have to inspect the generated assembly. It can get *really* complicated, *really* fast, for some types of bugs. Different compilers may also generate different results - lots of variables.